# How to Realtime Vue from vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have to continue to develop from others. But a value is passed vuex.

```
  mounted() {
   this.fetch();
  },
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getValue'])
  },

 methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetch']),
    ...mapMutations({}),
    async scrollBottom() {
      this.fetch();
      }
  }
```

getValue is data .
fetch is a action > edit delete

if refresh page is true work properly But I would like it to be real time.
Can I have some advice?
And it would help me a lot if you have the right example.

Comment: If the data being returned from `fetch` is intended to be in real time, then server side events or web sockets should be utilized. Otherwise, if semi-real time functionality is desired, simply set up a long polling xhr request to continually get this data from the server.